# Search one table at a time from multiple tables with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some working js that searches a table based on text provided via an input element. Each table has its own input element. All tables have the same class name and so do all input elements. How do I use jquery to specify 'this' particular input should search only in the next table below it.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".searchTable").on("keyup", function () {

    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $(".matchTable tr").filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });

  });
});
```

html

```
<div class="pbTable">
    <div class="name">
      <input type="search" name="" value="" placeholder="SEARCH" class="searchTable">
    </div>

    <table class="matchTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>heading</th>
          <th>heading</th>
          <th>heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
<div class="pbTable">
    <div class="name">
      <input type="search" name="" value="" placeholder="SEARCH" class="searchTable">
    </div>

    <table class="matchTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>heading</th>
          <th>heading</th>
          <th>heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
          <td>data</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
```

Comment: This can help with indexed based selection: https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: what is the `.searchTable` position in al these code snippets?

Comment: @seethrough just edited the markup to reflect that

Comment: put `$(this).closest('.pbTable').find(".matchTable tr").filter(function () {` instead of `$(".matchTable tr").filter(function () {`

Comment: @seethrough it works. Thanks. Wanna put that as an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should make it work

```
  $(".searchTable").on("keyup", function () {

    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $(this).closest('.pbTable').find(".matchTable tr").filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get current table by looking at the parent of the current input.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".searchTable").on("keyup", function () {

    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var table = $(this.parentNode.parentNode).find('.matchTable')[0];

    $(table).find("tr").filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });

  });
});
```